# How do you display a message in web forms using .cs code in visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#

In visual studio 2005, we can get message.show() to display the message.I required the method in visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that there is any change in the code from VS2005 to VS2008.
But accordnig to the title of your question ("diplay a message in web forms"), I assume that you are using ASP.NET (if you meant win forms, RichardOD has already answered your question).

You should use javascript function

```
alert('This is my message.');
```

to show the message.

Check [this](http://www.webpronews.com/expertarticles/2006/11/29/javascript-alertshowmessage-from-aspnet-codebehind) article - it contains a great implementation that you can use right as a MessageBox in winforms.

Answer (score 3):

if it is webform, you could use

```
Response.Write("Your Message")
```

Method.. if you want the message box, you could use javascript

```
alert('your message')
```

if it is windows forms, use

```
Messagebox.Show("your message")
```

hope this helps u

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't changed in 2008. Are you sure you mean Web forms, it sounds more like you mean Windows Forms- see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx

If you need further help please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean MessageBox.Show(). MessageBox is a class in the System.Windows.Forms namespace; this class contains the Show method which when called, should draw a window on a screen. Now this is all different with web! Web is not a one machine application like your windows form, web is a client/server architecture, where there are two major parts of your application: the server where you deploy your code, and the client (the  browser responsible for rendering the output of your code). I will not digg in much details for now, I strongly recommend that you learn about the web and its Client/Server architecture first.
 Thanks